# Python Noob: Input returning as none

Tags: python

Im still very new when it comes to python so be easy on me. Whenever I test this code it comes back with "None" instead of the input entered. Any idea why it could be happening?

```
def inputLandValue():
    while(1):
        try:
            value=int(input('Please enter the value of the property '))
            break
        except:
            print('Please enter a whole number (10000)')
            return value
def main():
    while(1):
        landValue = inputLandValue()
        print(landValue)
        doMoreStuff = input('Do you want to continue? y/n ')
        if(doMoreStuff.lower() != 'y'):
            break
main()
input()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You indented your `return value` line too far. It is part of the `except:` handler, so it is only executed when you have *no `value`*! It should be *outside* the `while` loop:

```
def inputLandValue():
    while(1):
        try:
            value=int(input('Please enter the value of the property '))
            break
        except:
            print('Please enter a whole number (10000)')
    return value
```

or replace the `break` with `return value`:

```
def inputLandValue():
    while(1):
        try:
            value=int(input('Please enter the value of the property '))
            return value
        except:
            print('Please enter a whole number (10000)')
```

You should really only catch `ValueError` however; this isn't Pokemon, don't try to catch'm all:

```
except ValueError:
```

Comment: I would like to give an other +1 for the pokemon reference !

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by just putting '`return value`' in place of the `break` in `main()`.